# Getting real IP with MUP and SSL

Tags: ssl, meteor, nginx, https, proxy

We are using MUP for Meteor deployment to AWS. Couple of weeks ago we got excited that we can now switch to a free cert, thanks to [Letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) and [Kadira](https://voice.kadira.io/meteor-up-let-s-encrypt-based-free-ssl-d17111f69f15#.k6eahm131). Everything was working very nicely, until I realized in the logs that client IP is no longer being passed through the proxy... No matter what I do, I see `127.0.0.1` as my client IP. I was trying to get it in methods using `this.connection.clientIP` or [headers](https://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/headers) package.

Well, after doing much research and learning in-depth how stub and nginx work, I came to conclusion that this was never working.

The best solution I came up with is to use [proxy_protocol](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/proxy-protocol/) as [described by Chris](https://chrislea.com/2014/03/20/using-proxy-protocol-nginx/), but I could not get it to work.

I have played with settings of `/opt/stud/stud.conf` and attempted to turn `write-proxy` and `proxy-proxy` settings on.

This is what my nginx config looks like:

```
server {
  listen                80 proxy_protocol;
  server_name           www.example.com example.com;

  set_real_ip_from      127.0.0.1;
  real_ip_header        proxy_protocol;
  access_log            /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/example.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
  }
}
```

Here is what my headers look like on production EC2 server:

```
  accept:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
  accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate, sdch"
  accept-language:"en-US,en;q=0.8"
  cache-control:"no-cache"
  connection:"upgrade"
  host:"127.0.0.1:3000"
  pragma:"no-cache"
  upgrade-insecure-requests:"1"
  x-forwarded-for:"127.0.0.1"
  x-forwarded-proto:"http"
  x-ip-chain:"127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1"
  x-real-ip:"127.0.0.1"
```

So, the questions of the day. Using MUP with SSL, is there a way to get a pass-though client IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so after a sleepless night and learning everything I could about the way STUD and HAProxy protocol works, I came to a simple conclusion it's simply not supported.

I knew I could easily go back to have SSL termination at Nginx, but I wanted to make sure that my deployment has automation as MUP.

Solution? [MUPX](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx). The next version of MUP, but still in development. It uses Docker and has SSL termination directly at Nginx.

So there you have it. Lesson? `Stable` is not always a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you have tried using [headers](https://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/headers), but you may give it another shot and see if you can get something this way. I was having alot of problems with x-forwarded-for counts not staying consistent, but if I pull from the header chain, [0] is always the client IP.

Put this code in your /server folder:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getIP: function() {
    var header = this.connection.httpHeaders;
    var ipAddress = header['x-forwarded-for'].split(',')[0];
    return ipAddress;
  }
});
```

In your browser console:

```
Meteor.call('getIP', function(err, result){
  if(!err){
    console.log(result);
  } else {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

See what you get from that response. If that works, you can just call the method on Template.rendered or whenever you need the IP.

Otherwise, I'm pretty sure you should be able to set the IP to an arbitrary header in your nginx conf and then access it directly in the `req` object.

Comment: The problem is, I can't get that IP anywhere in the config... It's not even being sent to nginx since SSL is being terminated at stud

Answer (score 0):

By the way, in the nginx config you included, I think you need to use `real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;` so that real_ip will use that header to locate the client IP, and you should also set `real_ip_recursive on;` so that it will ignore your trusted `set_real_ip_from`

Comment: That didn't help still getting `127.0.0.1` across the board